# save checkedlistbox in the scope

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have a word button that creates a table with checkedlistboxes
the problem is that the checkedlistbox created only inside this function.
later on, when I am trying to access the checkedlistbox (see which checkbox is marked) from a different function I can't do this.

I am using word ribbon

the code for the checkedlistbox

```
            Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.CheckedListBox listBox1;
            Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
            extendedDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
            listBox1 = extendedDocument.Controls.AddCheckedListBox(newTable.Cell(i , 2).Range, 90, 66.75F, "checkedListBox1" + i);
            //listBox1.Name = xlDDLRange.Cells[j, i].Value2.ToString();
            // MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Name);
            //CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection;
            listBox1.IntegralHeight = true;
            int j = 1;
            int range = ColumnRange(i );

            while (true)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(xlDDLRange.Cells[j, i].Value2.ToString());
                if (j == range) break;
                // Add items that are wide to the ListBox.
                listBox1.Items.Add(xlDDLRange.Cells[j+1 , i ].Value2.ToString());
                j++;
            }
```

now I am trying with a diffrent function to check which checkboxes are marked

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Can someone please help me?

I am desperate

Comment: Please share some relevant code and let us know what's not working. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access word checkboxlist and check if check mark in checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523729/access-word-checkboxlist-and-check-if-check-mark-in-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

This code "checkedListBox MouseClick" event write this code

Selected Index Number : checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;

Selected İndex value  : checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace windowsfirewalladd
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void checkedListBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Index Number :" + checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex + "\n" + "Selected İndex value :" + checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Comment: but I am using a word checkedboxlist , and I dont have access to my checkedboxlist.
I added a code

Answer (score 0):

If you using dynamic create checkbox, you can use delegate method like

```
delete.MouseLeave += delete_MouseLeave;



void delete_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```